# How to calculate time complexity O(n) of the algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity

What I have done:
I measured the time spent processing 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 items.
 Measurements here: https://github.com/DimaBond174/cache_single_thread
.

Then I assumed that O(n) increases in proportion to n, and calculated the remaining algorithms with respect to O(n) ..

Having time measurements for processing 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 items how can we now attribute the algorithm to O(1), O(log n), O(n), O(n log n), or O(n^2) ?

Comment: Am I missing something here? Please show the algorithm in question. If the algorithm is unknown, then you can only guess, and you'll get an infinite number of candidates, which all depend on how many measurements you take.

Comment: @RmbRT, I compare 5 algorithms and analyze their speed. These algorithms occupy several files in several classes - this is too much code to upload it here. I brought the link to source codes:
https://github.com/DimaBond174/cache_single_thread

I asked the question of calculating O (n) at several sites and no one seems to be able to count in reality. Everyone has only a subjective unjustified assessment, which does not take into account all factors.

Answer (score 7):

Let's define N as one of the possible inputs of data. An algorithm can have different Big O values depending on which input you're referring to, but generally there's only one big input that you care about. Without the algorithm in question, you can only guess. However there are some guidelines that will help you determine which it is.

**General Rule:**

**O(1)** - the speed of the program barely changes regardless of size of data. To get this, a program must not have loops operating on the data in question at all.

**O(log N)** - the program slows down slightly when N increases dramatically, in a logarithmic curve. To get this, loops must only go through a fraction of the data. (for example, binary search).

**O(N)** - the program's speed is directly proportional to the size of the data input. If you perform an operation on each unit of the data, you get this. You must not have any kind of nested loops (that act on the data).

**O(N log N)**- the program's speed is significantly reduced by larger input. This occurs when you have a O(logN) operation NESTED in a loop that would otherwise be O(N). So for example, you had a loop that did a binary search for each unit of data.

**O(N^2)** - The program will slow down to a crawl with larger input and eventually stall with large enough data. This happens when you have NESTED loops. Same as above, but this time the nested loop is O(N) instead of O(log N)

So, try to think of a looping operation as O(N) or O(log N). Then, whenever you have nesting, multiply them together. If the loops are NOT nested, they are not multiplied like this. So two loops separate from each other would simply be O(2N) and not O(N^2).

Also remember that you may have loops under the hood, so you should think about them too. For example, if you did something like Arrays.sort(X) in Java, that would be a O(N logN) operation. So if you have that inside a loop for some reason, your program is going to be a lot slower than you think.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to measure exactly which curve the algorithm behaves closer to. And as it seems to me, I found the right testing methodology.However, there are people who consider my methodology not accurate:
https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/axh6x8/new_lru_cache_algorithm_faster_than_qt_qcache/
If you're interested, here are the Excel files where I calculate the time complexity O(n):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZPpN-3KY_DuopkFFmDlrPPm-fViBAqZs

Comment: @Helsing Please note that "O(n)" in the Big-O notation is one specific complexity class, and not a general term for "complexity class of the algorithm". You make it sound in your introduction as if that were the case. Please clarify that what we are determining is the asymptotic time complexity class of an algorithm.

Comment: @RmbRT okay I clarified